# Javascript auto scroll page up and down and refresh the data periodically

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am working on a alert board which needs to scroll up and down slowly - and every couple of minutes get more data using Ajax (for that I already have a function called getData())

So far I've got:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            getData();

            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 20000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 20000);
            }, 10);
            var scrolltopbottom = setInterval(function () {

                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 20000);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 20000);
                }, 100);

            }, 2000);
            getData();

        });
```

---

However this only scrolls the page and doesn't get to call getData()

Ideally I'd like to scroll the page up and down automatically so people can read the page, no mater how much data is on it and every 2 minutes call getData() to refresh the data.

The page contains a simple table which may have x amount of rows - that amount will alter as the getData() is called.

getData()  code

```
function getData() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: #url#,
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (data) {

                        $("#alarms tr").remove(); 


                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                    $("#alarms").prepend("<tr class=\"bg-danger\"><td>" + item.name + "</td></tr>");
                                }
                        });
                        $("#refreshed").text(new Date().toLocaleString());
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        $('body').html('<span style="color: red;"><h2>Error retrieving data<!/h1><br/><h3>' + thrownError + '</h3></span>');
                    }
                });
```

the html page just has a table with thead and tbody

Comment: also add hear your getData() function code too.

Comment: @dev_ramiz_1707 - added that in too.

Comment: please check you url in browser and see there is any data

Comment: yes there is, about 25 rows get created. This works for the first call of GetData() but not the subsequent one. The question I have is how do you make the page scroll up and down by it self, whilst refreshing the data every 2 minutes.

Comment: okay i understand you whole questions. but you didn't create auto load new data code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer - can you show me what you mean? Calling GetData() might result in new data, but might be the same as last time - it's a dynamic feed that depends on another system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code may be it helps you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            getData();

            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 20000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 20000);
            }, 10);
            var scrolltopbottom = setInterval(function () {

                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 20000);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 20000);
                }, 100);
                getData();
            }, 2000);


        });
```

thanks